# Java method wrapping with keywords

Tags: java, selenium, testing, frameworks, automation

I am writing a Java keyword driven framework. In that I have one keyword Java class which I am calling in another Java test class.

```
KeywordClass doactionobje = new KeywordClasss();
doactionObje.click(parameter1,...);
```

Now I am looking to wrap this method calling in single keyword. For e.g.
`doactionObje.click` should be only `click` similar `doactionobje.input` to only `input`.

New code will look like

```
click parameter1, parameter2
```

I want to achieve this to make test script writing easier for those who do not have much coding experience.

I would also like to know about your thoughts on performance of script execution and other maintenance over ahead.

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (encouraging you to look at it as you scrolled past) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers. I've fixed some of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The directive you might be looking for is `import static`, i.e.

```
import static java.util.Collections.*;
```

will import all the static methods from the `java.util.Collections` class. However, there is no way to do this for non-static methods.

Comment: Thanks. just wondering if a wrapper can be put around the keywords which will map to the methods.